# GKE Kubernetes LoadBalancer returns connection reset by peer

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

i have encountered a strange problem with my cluster

in my cluster i have a deployment and a Loadbalancer service exposing this deployment
it worked like a charm but suddenly the Loadbalancer started to return an error:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

the error is showing while the pod and the loadbalancer are running and have no errors in their logs

what i already tried:

- deleting the pod
- redeploying service + deployment from scratch
  but the issue persist

my service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"RELEASE-NAME","app.kubernetes.io/name":"APP-NAME","app.kubernetes.io/version":"latest"},"name":"APP-NAME","namespace":"namespacex"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"web","port":3000}],"selector":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"RELEASE-NAME","app.kubernetes.io/name":"APP-NAME"},"type":"LoadBalancer"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-08-03T07:55:00Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/name: APP-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/version: latest
  name: APP-NAME
  namespace: namespacex
  resourceVersion: "14583904"
  uid: 7fb4d7e6-4316-44e5-8f9b-7a466bc776da
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.4.18.36
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.4.18.36
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: web
    nodePort: 30970
    port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/name: APP-NAME
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

my deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: APP-NAME
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: APP-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "latest"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: APP-NAME
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: 5e6ff0d6fa64b90b0365e9f3939cefc0a619502b32564c4ff712067dbe44ab90
        checksum/secret: 76e0a1351da90c0cef06851e3aa9e7c80b415c29b11f473d4a2520ade9c892ce
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: APP-NAME
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: APP-NAME
      containers:
        - name: APP-NAME
          image: 'docker.io/xxxxxxxx:latest'
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 3000
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /balancer/
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /balancer/
              port: http
          env:
            ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /home/app/config/
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 400m
              memory: 256Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 400m
              memory: 256Mi
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: app-config
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: secret
```

Comment: Can you connect to your application from inside the cluster?

Comment: yes, the app operates fine if i access it from the inside

Comment: Are you using workload identity for your cluster? Do the pods have sidecar injection enabled? This may be related to istio-proxy blocking the connection to metadata server. If sidecar injector is removed from the pods, the traffic starts working fine and pods are able to fetch token details from metadata server.

Comment: Could you provide a way for reproducing this behavior on a test cluster ? Since we can't use the same image nor we're aware of all the details of your configuration we're not able to reproduce it based on the information you shared so far.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in my case turned to be a network component (like a FW) blocking the outbound connection after dimming the cluster 'unsafe' for no apparent reason

so in essence it was not a K8s issue but an IT one